# Why don't use Laravel 5.1 Aliases?

Tags: laravel-5.1

in Laravel 5.1 by default the Authentication import the "Request"-class by "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" and call the class by "$request->all()".

Why Laravel don't use aliases, "use Request;" and "Request::all()"?

What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.x prefers method dependency injection over facades in generally.

Comment: So is this way "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" the newer and better way than Aliases?

Comment: Well, "better" - I don't know. Personally I stick with good old facades.